# superfish ie8 visited menu changes size

Tags: jquery, joomla, superfish

I have a site [cmse.bemoore.com](http://cmse.bemoore.com).  If it is viewed in IE8, when you click on the superfish menu, the size changes. This doesn't happen in any other browser I have tested. How do I fix this?

Thanks

Comment: post your css code of superfish

Comment: Hi Alessandro, I just fixed it, will post solution below...

Comment: I fixed this, the problem was:

.top-nav-bar a:link, a:visited {
color: #FFF!important;
text-decoration: none;
font-size: 10px;
font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
margin-left: 10px;
}

Of course the a:visited above should have been .top-nav-bar a:visited.

Comment: I'm not allowed answer my own question for 7 hours :(

Comment: waiting 7 hours not so far :)